# How do I prevent Intellij IDEA from reformatting interpolated strings in Scala?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I noticed recently when I Code / Reformat Code a Scala source file, it turns this:

```
log.info(s"$me: ${observations.size} observations, ${set.size} missing stationId, ${observations.size - set.size} usable")
```

into this:

```
log.info(s"$me: ${
  observations.size
} observations, ${
  set.size
} missing stationId, ${
  observations.size - set.size
} usable")
```

That's kind of interesting, but sometimes I want to keep the one-liner. Is there a preference in IDEA to have it not do that?

Comment: Haha, wow, I haven't seen that, but IDEA is so annoying sometimes, how it tries to "help" me...

Comment: which intellij version are you using? I am using the latest and don't have this issue.

Comment: @TomerShetah 2020.3

Comment: And which scala plugin version?

Comment: @TomerShetah Scala plugin 4.42 JetBrains Mar 02, 2021 (Languages 2020.3.20)

Comment: Do you get the same if you are just defining `val x = s"$me: ${observations.size} observations, ${set.size} missing stationId, ${observations.size - set.size} usable"`?